# Resolution settings don't include 1600x900

Tags: display-resolution

I'm running the latest ubuntu on a thinkpad t470s and I can't change my screen resolution to 1600x900 which would look the best on the screen i'm using. I've tried to add it manually with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Lenovo Thinkpad T470s may come with a FHD (1920 x 1080) or a WQHD (2560 X 1440) display, neither "look better" with a lower resolution. The native resolution is the only one you should use, always. If the problem is let's say too small icons/text with the WQHD screen, that's a matter of scaling - you may need 150% -, not resolution.

Comment: I agree with MichaelBay. However this [X configuration guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) could help.

Comment: Oh hey @MichaelBay that looks a lot better. Thanks!